# Syntax error using IS NOT in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Can anyone help my find this syntax error?

```
SELECT `song`, COUNT(*)
FROM `2015_awards`
WHERE `song` IS NOT `NoVote`
GROUP BY `song`;
```

I'm trying to exclude NoVote songs, and it won't work. Everything else is fine. When I Google problems like this, it looks as though it should work.

Comment: `IS NOT` is not an equality operator in SQL (it is used for `NULL` checks).  You want  `WHERE song <> 'NoVote'` Assuming 'NoVote' is a song string value and not a column name.

Comment: `IS NOT` expects  `boolean_value` not a **string**

Comment: The backticks around "NoVote" are incorrect, assuming you meant a string - backticks are for column names.

Comment: [Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html): `IS [NOT] {NULL|[boolean_value]}`.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much, yes, it is a song string value not a column name, and <> works.

Answer (score 3):

`IS NOT` is wrong. What you probably need to use is `<>`.

Comment: Yep - perfect, see my comment above.  It works - many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cant not use pass NoVote as a value to `IS` or `IS NOT`
Try this:

```
SELECT song, COUNT(*) FROM 2015_awards WHERE song != 'NoVote' GROUP BY song;
```

Comment: Yes - this also works perfectly, so now I have 2 solutions where I had none before, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `IS` Keyword is only for `NULL` comparisons. 
As Pigasus says, you probably should be using `<>`.

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Yes - as my previous comment, it does work.  I hadn't realised that IS just works for NULL.  Very useful info - thanks